# nodejs call two class functions synchronous

Tags: node.js, callback, synchronous

I have two class functions in nodejs and I want to call both synchronously both one after another.

```
var questionData = questionModelObj.getQuestionbyId(req.params.id);
var answerData = answerModelObj.getAnsByQuesId(req.params.id);
```

Here questionModelObj take time to execute and it calls answerModelObj without completing questionModelObj. It results answerData overwrites the questionData.

Please suggest how to call these two functions one after another(synchronous) and explain.

Comment: There are two predominant options, executing `answerModelObj` in a callback function from `questionModelObj` or having `questionModelObj` return a promise. Beyond that, this question is too vague and likely to be marked as duplicate.

Comment: hi @daviscodesbugs , please explain with example in answer.

Comment: Could you add the function definitions for `getQuestionbyId` and `getAnsByQuesId` and any other useful information for more clarity?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to execute the second function as a callback to the first. This is pretty standard for Javascript.

```
// Declare variable to hold response
var answerData;

var questionData = questionModelObj.getQuestionbyId(req.params.id, function() {
    // This is the callback function
    answerData = answerModelObj.getAnsByQuesId(req.params.id);
}
```

The function signature of `getQuestionbyId` would then need to take in 2 parameters, the second being a function to be called later on:

```
questionModelObj.getQuestionbyId = function(id, callback) {
    // Do things with the id
    callback();
}
```

The callback function is then called *after* `getQuestionbyId` is done.

Comment: If I go with first one than do I need to change in the existing function. because I implemented this but it returns `undefined`

Comment: Hey Amit, nodeJS is built to be asynchronous, to achieve a synchronous effect here you would have to implement a callback function

Comment: `questionModelObj.getQuestionbyId(req.params.id, function(questionData){
answerModelObj.getAnsByQuesId(req.params.id, function(answerData){
          //Use questionData and answerData here
));

});`

Comment: Important to note that with @GregRebisz code, the two function signatures should also expect and call the provided callbacks